# How to remove html tags wrapping a specific word of a long text

Tags: php, strip-tags

How to remove tags wrapping a specific word within a text, For example see the sample text below

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ##<strong>REPLACETEXT<strong>## ligula bibendum, imperdiet quam sit amet, fringilla lacus. Quisque sit amet tincidunt justo

What I need is to remove <strong> tag from the text ie the text should read like ##REPLACETEXT##,

Please note: Any of the html tag may come instead of strong eg ##<span>REPLACETEXT<span>##, Also I dont want to remove tags wrapping the words other than REPLACETEXT

Is there any php trick to remove such occurance of tag for my replace text

Comment: Have you tried strip_tags https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I dont want to remove tags wrapping any words other  than REPLACETEXT

Comment: Since you want to replace tags of which you don’t know the tag name, you would need to use some kind of pattern matching, which usually means regular expressions. Manipulating HTML using regular expressions is not recommended in general, but I think for such a limited use case it might be okay. The other alternative would be to use a proper DOM parser, locate the text node that consists of `REPLACETEXT`, append that before its parent node, and then remove that parent node afterwards.

Comment: @ascsoftw Why downvote. Strip tags doest fix my requirement

Comment: @Ajith I didn't downvoted your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove tags from the html, in php use:

`strip_tags($text)`

if you want to remove all tags except one or two use:

`strip_tags($text, 'elementTag, elementTag')`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#example-6136

Comment: What I need is to remove any of the tags that happend to come wrapping REPLACETEXT     ie: if text is ##<span>REPLACETEXT</span>##    I should get ##REPLACETEXT##